# One of the cotroller line meaning in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I working in codeigniter php. I am novice in this frame work.

In controller i use this line. 
But i don't know whats the meaning of this line.

```
 $data['admin_id']=$this->session->userdata('admin_id');
```

Comment: `userdata()` method (of CodeIgniter Session library) retrieves the session data using a key.

Answer (score 0):

`admin_id` is stored in session. You are assigning the `admin_id` from session to data array which may passed to view file.

For CI session tutorial:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html